# auto select credit card type

Tags: php, sql, validation

i am building payment form 
and want auto select credit card type with the 1st 4 digits 
i have the valid ranges on Visa Master AMEX Discover

here an example of Discover one

```
validRanges":["6282","6283","6284","6285","67","66","6287","6286","6288","64","65","63888","6011","622","624","625","626"]
```

how may i build input that auto select discover card and appear the discover icon 
and disapper other ones

somethink like this

https://www.panic.com/coda/buy.html

Answer (score 0):

You are surely going to need Javascript for that kind of effect. And assuming you are storing that data on the server (possibly in the database) you'll need *AJAX* to query the database and find out if the inputted digits are part of any range in the database.

For the Javascript part I suggest you to take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com): specifically [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and the function [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/).

The basic idea you are going to implement is basically the following:

1. Detect any user digit input
2. Take the `<input>` input and send it (via [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)) to a PHP script `x.php`
3. `x.php` processes the inputted data (possibly sent via POST method) and queries the database returning a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) array of card types to the client side
4. The client side convert the JSON string to actual JSON objects and use it to hide or show specific divs representing the cards.

Comment: thanks for answer i need it load on the same time sorry for littel knowlage of ajax the input of creditcard number is  'cardnumber' and the test digit is validRanges":["6282","6283","6284","6285","67","66","6287","6286","6288","64","65","63888","6011","622","624","625","626"]  so may you tell me what the exactly will be the code

Comment: @user2280740, I'm sorry. Here on SO we shouldn't really do that. SO is not made to provide code without any effort by the OP. You'll have to study Javascript and AJAX by your own and then come back here when you'll have a more concrete problem then "I just want the code". Good luck.

Comment: understood i just need example